# htaccess configuration for pretty url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm developing a website and I need to get the pretty url.

After a couple of hours spent reading tons of tutorials, it always give me back an error..

I create the .htaccess file in the root directory (www.mysite.com/.htaccess).

I would the url beacame form *www.mysite.com/subdirectory/news.php* to *www.mysite.com/subdirectory/news/*

I tried with

*RewriteRule ^subdirecotry/news.php$ www.mysite.com/subdirectory/news [L]*

but it did not work.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(subdirecotry/news)\.php/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(subdirecotry/news)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: $1 must be declared somewhere?

Comment: `$1` is actually the 1st group i.e. text within parenthesis. So here `$1` would be `subdirecotry/news`

Comment: mmm, i tried. when i go to _http://www.mysite.com/subdirectory/news/_ firefox give me back the 404 error.. if i go to _www.mysite.com/subdirectory/news.php_ instead, it redirect me to _http://www.mysite.com/web/htdocs/www.mysite.com/home/subdirectory/news_

Comment: thank you! i'm going to try it right now and i'll let you know!

Comment: Did you load mod_rewrite and enabled Rewrite engine?

Comment: yes, RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(subdirecotry/news)\.php/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(subdirecotry/news)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]

Comment: Ok tell me what happens when you enter this URL: `http://mysite.com/subdirectory/news.php`

Comment: it redirect me to _http://www.mysite.com/sub/news_ and give me back the 404 error

Comment: Alright that is good to know (at least something is working). Now comment out first 2 lines in my code above and then retry same URI i.e. `http://mysite.com/subdirectory/news.php`

Comment: `works regular`: I believe it means it is working fine and displaying content in the browser. Now can you try `http://mysite.com/subdirectory/news` again? If this doesn't work change last rule to: `RewriteRule ^(subdirecotry/news)/?$ $1.php [R,L,NC]` and try again? Also keep in mind that `subdirectory` is just a placeholder and you need to replace it with actual directory name you have.

Comment: changed it as you told me, 'RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(merqana/news)/?$ $1.php [R,L,NC]' , but if i go to www.mysite.com/sub/news, it gives me 404 error :(((

Comment: Don't you need to go to: `www.mysite.com/merqana/news`? Also I believe this .htaccess is in $DOCUMENT_ROOT folder. Do you by chance  have another .htaccess in the `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/merqana/` directory?

Comment: yes, i need to digit `www.mysite.com/merqana/news` and load the content of `www.mysite.com/merqana/news.php`, without visualizing the .php page on the url toolbar. the htaccess is locatend on the root folder www.mysite.com/.htaccess and i have not another htacces under merqana directory

Comment: This is most basic of mod_rwrite and fully working on my server. Ok final attempt and then I give up. Can you change last rule to: `RewriteRule ^merqana/news$ /merqana/news.php [L,NC]` and see if that makes any dfference.

Comment: it doesn't work :( do you think is a good idea to create subdirctory's folder with a index.php file inside to solve the problem?

Comment: No index.php in merqana will not help. Looks like there is some localized problem in your config which I'm unable to guess from here. If you want you can read on how to enable RewriteLog in httpd.conf and then enable RewriteLog. See what output you get there. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, Problem solved! That's the sintax i used. '
RewriteRule ^sub/news/$ sub/notizie.php [L]'. the name of the file.php and the name of the directory (sub/news/) in this case CAN NOT be the same!! that's way it give me back the error!