# how to hide the current page name from address bar

Tags: php

I want my URL to look like this in Address bar 
**http://mysite.com/** 
instead of 
**http://mysite.com/somepage.html** or  **.php**   
i want to do this in all of my page in my website 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use rewrite rules.  If you search around, you will find a few thousand posts about this.

Comment: That doesn't actually make much sense.  What should happen when the user clicks a link?

Comment: Well, you certainly can't have **all** pages just show as `http://mysite.com`, not without loading everything via ajax, or similar.

Comment: What do you mean by "do this"? Is it "`http://mysite.com/otherpage.html` is `http://mysite.com/`" or "`http://mysite.com/otherpage.html` is `http://mysite.com/otherpage/`"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess configuration for pretty url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556225/htaccess-configuration-for-pretty-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enable mod_rewirte in your apache server and call your page as 
Call your pages like:

```
http://mysite.com/11/news
or 
http://mysite.com/11/blog
```

Add .htaccess file in your root directory-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ viewnews.php?news_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ blog.php?news_id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put an iframe that contains the content of your site with the size as big as the window

So, everytime user clicks link the iframe changes the content without changing your site URL

Or you can use this method: http://html5demos.com/history